# Return HttpNot Found Does't redirect to custom error page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a ASP MVC Web Application. I added a custom error page for the Error 404 Form. The custom error section in web config looks like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/errors/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```

I have a controller which returns HttpNotFound result

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

The problem is that it shows the default error 404 page instead of my custom one.

Comment: is `/errors/Error404` resolved properly? try `~/errors/Error404`

Comment: yes it's resolved properly and works fine with normal 404 error the all problem comes with the return not found

Comment: are you returning that as a response of an ajax call?

Comment: Did you try what happen if you  try to call a resource that really doesn't exist? I mean not a controller which return HttpNotFound but a controller that is not implemented.

Comment: Because is the  controller to return the HttpNotFound maybe is not intercepted and not handled. The browser receive the status code 404 as result of your controller and then show it own default page for 404 error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above because is the controller to return the HttpNotFound it is not intercepted and not handled. The browser receive the status code 404 as result of your controller and then the browser show it own default page for 404 error

try to call: `throw new HttpException(404, "Not found")` in the controller action instead of `HttpNotFound`

Comment: thanks a lot it works really fine but if there is another solution would be better as this actually throws exception which will be stored in my exception log and it's not very necessary but any way it works thanks :)

Comment: In my case it's not browser default page for 404. It actually shows IIS 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw HttpException message or redirect to appropriate error page instead of **HttpNotFound()**:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("NotFound","Error");
```

Better use the return statement as if there's a global try-catch, the first statement will not show error page.